# Arrays in Assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, masm

I am having some issues with my output...I think I have some problems with my array.  Still kind of new to assembly.  The assignment is to design an assembly program that uses a dialog box to prompt the user for a number.  These numbers will be stored in an array.  There will be an output message that shows the following: sum of numbers entered, how many numbers were entered(not counting the -9999 to end the program), the average of the numbers, and the count of array entries that are greater that or equal to the average value. All help is appreciated!  Here is what I have:

```
.DATA
numArray    DWORD   ?
numElts     DWORD   100
num         DWORD   ?
exitNum     DWORD   -9999
prompt      BYTE    "Enter a number", 0
string      BYTE    40 DUP (?)
resultLbl   BYTE    "Results", 0
sum         BYTE    11 DUP(?), " is the sum.", 0dh, 0ah
;numEntered BYTE    11 DUP(?), " numbers were entered."
avg         BYTE    11 DUP(?), " is the average."
count       BYTE    11 DUP(?), " is the number of entries that are >= the     average."

.CODE
_MainProc PROC
            mov     eax, 0                      ; sum := 0
            lea     ebx, numArray               ; get address of     nbrArray

LOOP1:      input   prompt, string, 40          ; read ASCII   characters
            atod    string                      ; convert   to integer
            mov     num, eax                    ; store in memory
        mov     ecx, numElts                ; count := nbrElts
        cmp     exitNum, eax
        je      QUIT                        ; quit if -9999
        add     eax, [ebx]                  ; add number to sum
        add     ebx, 4                      ; get address of next array elt
        add     ecx, 1                      ; add one for count
        loop    LOOP1                       ; repeat nbrElts times

        cdq                                 ; extend sum to quadword
        idiv    numElts                     ; calculate average
        dtoa    avg, ebx                    ; convert to ASCII characters
        dtoa    count, ecx
        dtoa    sum, eax

QUIT:             
        output resultLbl, sum, avg, count
        ret

_MainProc ENDP
END                                             ; end of source code
```

Comment: is `atod` a custom function? cause generally `atod` converts to `double`, not integers, as such you want `atol`. Also, describing what your problem is would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

you are also using `EAX` to store your sum, but it'll be tainted by any call (specifically `atod`), you also don't sore the value in the array.
making your code a bit more smooth (broken into a few sections to make it simpler):

```
        mov     ecx, 100                   ; loop count (size of array)
        lea     ebx, numElts               ; get address of the array

LOOP1:  
        input   prompt, string, 40          ; read ASCII   characters
        push    ecx                         ; save the loop count incase
        atod    string                      ; convert   to integer
        pop     ecx                         ; restore the loop count
        mov     [ebx], eax                  ; store in the array            
        cmp     exitNum, eax
        je      NEXT                        ; quit if -9999
        add     ebx, 4                      ; get address of next array elt
        loop    LOOP1                       ; repeat nbrElts times
```

From here we can do the average, sum etc (I've done only the sum and average, rest is up to you).

```
NEXT:
mov ecx,100            ;loop count
lea ebx,numElts        ;array address
mov edx,0              ;sum

LOOP2:
mov eax,[ebx]                  ;get the num
cmp eax,exitNum                ;check for the sentinel
je DONE
add edx,eax                    ;increase the sum
add ebx,4                      ;next array element
loop LOOP2

DONE:
mov eax,100
sub eax,ecx                    ;get the number of entries processed
mov ecx,eax
mov eax,edx                    ;get ready to divide
push edx                       ;save the sum
mov edx,0
idiv ecx                       ;sum / count
pop edx                        ;restore the sum
;from here edx has your sum, eax has your average
```